# SQL date time difference between 2 columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help to figure out a simple code. I need to find the difference in 2 columns of my data set.
My table is ta1
Column 1 AS created - '6/16/21 4:57:00 PM'
Column 2 AS modified - '6/17/21 7:48:32 AM'

Query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTES, created , modified ) AS timediff
FROM ta1;
```

I Get an error because my columns have a date and time on them

Comment: What is the data type of your columns?  You are probably getting an error because the syntax of your `datediff()` is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a problems with params? [DateDiff Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datediff-function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f)

SELECT DATEDIFF(n, '6/16/21 4:57:00 PM' , '6/17/21 7:48:32 AM' ) AS timediff

Answer (score 0):

If your fields hold values of data type *DateTime*, use:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF("n", [created], [modified]) AS timediff
```

If your fields hold values of data type *Text*, first convert these to *DateTime*:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF("n", CDate([created]), CDate([modified])) AS timediff
```